# Error in scale_alpha_manual command: Error in alpha * 255 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: ggplot2, alpha

I'm attempting to graph a "between subjects" variable and a "within subjects" variable in the same graph by using Alpha to designate the "within subject" variable and fill to designate the "between subject" variable.

To do this I've been using the command `scale_alpha_manual` to designate which level of the variable should be see-through and which should be normal. It was working fine previously but then I updated ggplot2 and now I keep getting this error message:

```
Error in alpha * 255 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

It only occurs when I use `scale_alpha_manual`, so I'm pretty sure that's where the issue is coming from.  Is there anyway to work around this?

Here's the code for my graph:

```
ggplot(data=EPM_Dur_mean, aes(x=as.factor(Condition),y=meanDur, group=Condition, fill=Condition)) + 

geom_bar(data=EPM_Dur_mean, aes(alpha=Arm),show.legend=FALSE, stat="identity", position= position_dodge2(width=0.2)) +

geom_errorbar(data=EPM_Dur_mean, aes(ymin=meanDur-se,ymax=meanDur+se), position=position_dodge2(width=0.5,padding=0.5), show.legend=FALSE) +

theme_classic(base_size=20) +

scale_alpha_manual(values=c("Open"="0.3", "Closed"="1"))+

scale_fill_manual(values = c("Adol_0"="#0c2c84","Adol_50"="#c7e9b4", "Adult_0"="#49006a","Adult_50"="#fa9fb5"))+

scale_x_discrete(limits=c("Adol_0", "Adol_50", "Adult_0","Adult_50"), labels=c("0","50","0","50"))+

labs(x="", y="Duration (s)")+

geom_point(data=EPM_50, aes(x=Condition, y=Duration, group=Condition, color=Condition, shape=Cohort, alpha=Arm, size=3),position_dodge2(width=0.5), stat="identity")
```

[The graph is supposed to look like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTMMI.png)

Comment: Replace characters with numbers in `scale_alpha_manual(values=c("Open"="0.3", "Closed"="1"))`, i.e. `scale_alpha_manual(values=c("Open"=0.3, "Closed"=1))`

Comment: Thank you!! This worked!